# "Improper operand type" with MSVC __asm

Tags: visual-c++, assembly

I'm doing some random experimentation and want to print out the address the program is at at a given point. I tried doing the following, but it doesn't work:

```
void foo() {
    DWORD blah;
    __asm {
        mov blah, eip
    }
    std::cout << blah << "\n";
}
```

and instead gives "improper operand type" on the `mov` line.

I've tried several types for `blah`.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mov instruction that can touch the eip register. You'll have to use some kind trick to get its value.

[How to check the EIP value with assembly language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062403/how-to-check-the-eip-value-with-assembly-language)