# C++Builder - implement entire function in assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, c++builder, c++builder-xe5

I am trying to implement [this inline assembly trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062403/how-to-check-the-eip-value-with-assembly-language) to obtain the value of EIP in C++Builder. The following code works in Release mode:

```
unsigned long get_eip()
{
    asm { mov eax, [esp] }
}
```

however it doesn't work in Debug mode. In Debug mode the code has to be changed to this:

```
unsigned long get_eip()
{
    asm { mov eax, [esp+4] }
}
```

By inspecting the generated assembly; the difference is that in Debug mode the code generated for the `get_eip()` function (first version) is:

```
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
mov eax,[esp]
pop ebp
ret
```

however in Release mode the code is:

```
mov eax,[esp]
ret
```

Of course I could use `#ifdef NDEBUG` to work around the problem ; however is there any syntax I can use to specify that the whole function is in assembly and the compiler should not insert the `push ebp` stuff? (or otherwise solve this problem).

Comment: In Debug mode, stack frames are enabled by default. In Release mode, stack frames are disabled by default. There is a setting in the Project Options to control this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [__declspec(naked)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Declspec(naked))?

```
__declspec(naked) unsigned long get_eip()
{
    asm { mov eax, [esp] }
}
```

Comment: This worked after I changed it to `asm { mov eax, [esp]; ret }` - otherwise it fell through to whatever code was next!