# Get the value of EIP with x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

The accepted answer of [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062403/how-to-check-the-eip-value-with-assembly-language) gives the following solution:

```
get_eip: mov eax, [esp]
         ret
```

But I don't understand why this works. Why is the saved `EIP` pointed to by `ESP`? Shouldn't `ESP` be pointing to `SFP` (the old `EBP` value) at the time we execute the `mov` instruction? The prologue of a subroutine call in x86 assembly looks like:

```
push ebp      ; Save the old base pointer value
mov ebp, esp  ; Set the new base pointer value
sub esp, ...  ; Make room for local variable
```

So shouldn't the saved `EIP` sit one more word above the address where `ESP` is pointing to?

Comment: Yes, but this function as you can see has no such prologue.

Comment: @Jester Is that an exception for functions without local variables or something...?

Comment: That prologue is optional, and not typically used in optimized code. You only need the `sub esp` to allocate locals.

Comment: @ZizhengTai Nothing forces you to add a subroutine prologue and as you see, the `get_eip` function doesn't have such a prologue.

Comment: @fuz Oh, I see. The prologue is for functions written in higher-level languages (e.g., C/C+). We can write assembly functions however we like.

Comment: @ZizhengTai Good compilers for high-level languages too omit the function prologue when it is not needed or explicitly requested.

Comment: @ZizhengTai - You can think of it this way: Just before the `ret`, we *better have* `esp` point at the return address. Otherwise we will end up in the wrong place.