# GAS does not recognise register %ip

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, att

In my 16bit program GAS is balking at the instruction:

```
movw %ip, %dx
```

I find this strange as moving a segment register works fine, for example:

```
movw %ss, %ax
```

The full error message is:

> Error: bad register name `%ip'

And my version string is:

> GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.22

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, not every register can be easily accessed. There are some limitations.

As listed in [x86 wikibook, GPR section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture#General-Purpose_Registers_.28GPR.29), in x86 there are 8 General-Purpose Registers (GPRs): AX, CX, DX, BX, SP, BP, SI, DI, which can be used in many commands. They are encoded as 3 bits; and there is no space in the instruction encoding to encode Special registers, like EIP (IP), or EFLAGS (FLAGS).

If you scroll wikibook down, there is a section about IP:

> **Instruction Pointer**
>
> The EIP register contains the address of the next instruction to be executed if no branching is done.
>
> EIP can only be read through the stack after a call instruction.

So, it is really illegal to use mov to read IP.

There are some examples of reading ip with `call` then `pop %ax` sequence here: http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/x86_asm/267963/267963/how-to-access-ip-register/

Update: About reading of SS register:

There are actually many variant of mov instruction encoding, e.g. in this [table](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32-abc.html#M) we see segment reading

```
 mnemonic   op1 op2 po     o    description, notes 
 MOV    Sreg    r/m16   8E     r        Move
```

or Control Register writing:

```
 MOV    r32 CRn 0F20   r ...    Move to Control Registers
```

but there is still no MOV for IP register.

Update2: in x86_64 there is a reading of EIP with LEA, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1047968/196561

Comment: Can you explain, Where are you implementing a call?

Comment: well not a real call, but trying to save `%ip` into `%dx` (since I am not using %dx in my tiny subroutine), `jmp` to my subroutine, and then `jmp *%dx` to return.

Comment: Why not to use default stack and call/ret instead of jmp/jmp *dx? And I still see no obstacles to call/pop dx.

Comment: the purpose of this was to be used in helping me print out %ss in hex, since I have no idea where the stack is starting; I wanted to "call" my `convert_nibble_to_hex` subroutine with using the stack

Comment: but pair of `call near`/`pop dx` will compensate ss changes and after pair ss will be the same. call internals are listed here: http://www.fermi.mn.it/linux/quarta/x86/call.htm Other variant is just save ss in dx and call your function as usual to print dx register.

Comment: I don't have any idea where the stack is, that's why I wanted to print out `%ss`. If I remember correctly %ip starts at `$0x07c0` though

Comment: May be you need a debugger to find some information about your environment?

Comment: my environment is just BIOS+PXE x86 real mode, this is mostly just for the sake of learning assembly; anyway, you have answered my question, reading/writing to `%ip` is not possible.

Comment: The problem with a `call/pop` sequence is that you need a working stack for that, which might not be the case during OS startup.

Comment: @hirschhornsalz in retrospect maybe that's the question I should have asked, for what I needed I just worked around using a function, though from what I know now, I think there is actually a stack, albeit a small one, provided by the bios.